# How to cure bad spelling?

Tags: spelling, orthography

A friend who is a lawyer and reads a lot spells badly and it's affecting her practice. Spellcheckers are ok but they don't work in all cases, for instance when there are two words that sound the same but are spelled differently.

Checking spelling is slowing her down significantly, primarily because the only reliable way she's found is getting someone else to check it.

She is a native speaker.

Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Comment: This is a reasonable question, and worthy of an answer. If not here, where?

Comment: First, dyslexia should be ruled out. Then, you say she is a native speaker, but how are her reading skills? Also, could you add some examples of the kinds of words are misspelled? Some words such as homonyms have to be learned by experience where comprehension is context is important.

Comment: Yes I have a dozen ways on how to try to solve the problem. But the problem with your question is that it is opinion-based.

Comment: @Clare Maybe the question should be moved to [meta], where opinions are allowed. Just dismissing such questions as opinion based is not helpful to English language learners.

Comment: @Mick Meta is not a dumping ground for subjective questions that don't belong on the main site. A better strategy is to discuss opinion-based stuff in chat or to make the case that this isn't "bad subjective" and reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

One of my English teachers gave me some good advice. She suggested that if I was unsure of how to spell a word, I should look it up in a dictionary, and then write it down a few dozen times, maybe even a hundred times. This will fix the spelling in what is called *muscle memory*. Armed with this, if you cannot recall how to spell a word, say when you are typing, you just write it on a piece of paper, and your muscle memory will do the job for you. You may need to repeat the exercise several times, but it really works.

Unfortunately, this technique doesn't help with homophones that are spelt differently. For this, you need a crib sheet.

[Wikipedia: Muscle memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_memory)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think that Mick’s way of learning how to spell might work but it comes at the expense of your interest in learning English because rewriting words multiple times is quite a tedious and boring way to spell in my humble opinion.

I would recommend checking out this [Oxford Royale Academy website](https://www.oxford-royale.co.uk/articles/improve-english-spelling.html)  that gives a few tips and tricks on how to spell well.

Some of the techniques listed there are really effective and most of which I have used.

Just like most, if not all other languages, English gets better with use. Encourage your friend to write more in her free time and not just for work. For example, she could consider writing short stories from writing prompts or even do poetry! Not only will doing so increase her vocabulary, it might also help her spell better since she might need to use words that she did not originally know how to spell in her stories and poems.

To add on, I think that many English speakers and learners learn by implicit learning. This means that they do not actively memorize the spelling of words, grammar rules, ect. Instead, they gradually pick it up as they read more texts and listen to more people speak.

I think that we would be able to help more if you provide us with examples of words that she spells wrongly often so that we can find a more specific problem that she might be having.